How to fix cyghidapi-0.dll missing error cygwin
I am learning C and trying to do a project for class at home however, everytime I try to run I get the error
"error while loading shared libraries: cyghidapi-0.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"
I have tried reinstalling a few times and I do not know where to go from there.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

cygcheck -p cyghidapi-0.dll provides no info, so what software are you trying to use and from where you downloaded it ?
